# EF 7 AND between 2 where statements not working as expected

Tags: entity-framework

I read on SO that 2 `.Where` on `IQueryable` means AND between. But I have a case where this is not working as expected on master-details scheme.
This:

```
    query = query.Where(j => j.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.SubscriberId == 1));
    query = query.Where(j => j.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.DatetimeLastView < j.DatetimeUpdated));
```

returns more records then this:

```
    query = query.Where(j => j.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.DatetimeLastView < j.DatetimeUpdated && s.SubscriberId == 1));
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you use inner query and logic (mathematically) there is a bit different.

Example:

Assume you have following records in the Subscription table (ID, SubscriberId, (DatetimeLastView < DatetimeUpdated) as boolean)

- (s1, 1, true)
- (s2, 1, false)
- (s3, 2, true)

I'm not sure what `j` is but assume you have two records (ID, List of subscription IDs):

- (j1, [s1])
- (j2, [s2, s3])

Record j2 will not pass your second query but will pass your first one because there is a linked subscrition with `SubscriberId == 1` (s2) and there is a linked subscription with `s.DatetimeLastView < j.DatetimeUpdated` (s3) but there is no record with both.